# get the last row of a pandas DataFrame, as an iterable object

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to return an iterable object that consists of the values in the last row of a pandas DataFrame. This seems to work, though it's kind of verbose:

```
data.tail(1).itertuples(index=False).next()
# get the first item when iterating over the last 1 items as a tuple, 
#   excluding the index
```

Is there a simpler way, or is what I have the best?

---

edit: two important things:

- I'm *not* trying to achieve high performance (this is just the one row of a large table)
- the `.iloc[n]` accessor causes type coercion to create a Series object, and in my case the datatypes are heterogeneous (combinations of `int16`, `uint16` and `uint32`) and I need the types preserved.

Answer (score 3):

Access the underlying array with the `.values` attribute and unpack it into the builtin `iter` function.

```
In [29]: df = pd.DataFrame([['a', 'b'], ['c', 'a']], columns=['A', 'B'])

In [30]: df
Out[30]: 
   A  B
0  a  b
1  c  a

In [31]: gen = iter(*df.tail(1).values)

In [32]: next(gen)
Out[32]: 'c'

In [33]: next(gen)
Out[33]: 'a'

In [34]: next(gen)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
StopIteration                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-34-8a6233884a6c> in <module>()
----> 1 next(gen)

StopIteration:
```

You should think carefully about why you want to do this.  Vectorized operations are almost always better than iterative ones.